# Movement of electron in ac current

Tags: current, ac-dc, electron

Movement of electron direction in ac current is continuously changing which leads to more collision of electrons then dc current.From this can we conclude that ac current heated the wire more than dc current having same magnitude?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot say that there are more collisions in AC current. The power dissipated in a resistor with voltage \$v(t)\$ and current \$i(t)\$ is given by:
$$P(t) = v(t)i(t)$$
For an AC source, \$v(t) = Vsin(\omega t)\$ and \$i(t) = v(t)/R\$, thus,
$$P(t) = \frac{V^2sin^2(\omega t)}{R}$$
Average power is thus:
$$P_a = \frac{V^2}{2R}$$
For a DC voltage \$V_{DC}\$, the average power dissipated is:
$$P_a^\prime = \frac{V^2_{DC}}{R}$$
Since the power dissipated is converted into heat. The AC current with magnitude \$V\$ dissipates the same power as DC current with magnitude $$V_{DC} = \frac{V}{\sqrt{2}}$$
So actually if both AC and DC currents have same magnitude the DC current will draw more power as the AC current.
This can be expected since the current is flowing all the time for a DC voltage. But in case of AC voltage, current is zero at certain instants contributing to no power dissipation. Thus the average power dissipation is less for the AC source.

Answer (score 2):

> Movement of electron direction in ac current is continuously changing ...

I don't think that's quite right. The electric field is alternating in a sinusoidal fashion. It falls to zero twice per cycle.

> ... which leads to more collision of electrons then [than] DC current.

[image]

*Figure 1. The electric-field strength is the same in both cases. Only the sign changes. Source: [Electronics Tutorials](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/power/single-phase-rectification.html).*

It appears from one of your comments that by DC you mean full-wave rectified AC. So for AC you have \$ 220 sin(t) \$ and for DC you have \$ 220 |sin(t)| \$. The magnitude of the electric field will be the same in both cases. The current will be the same and the number of collisions will be the same.

> From this can we conclude that ac current heated the wire more than dc current having same magnitude?

No. It can't. Since \$ P = \frac {V^2} R \$ the result is always positive so direction of the current doesn't make any difference and the heating of the wire will be the same in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Flat out no, if you wanted to relate it back to electron motion, the average heating effect caused by the electron motion is equivalent to the RMS of that rate of motion, due to this, an AC motion under a peak voltage of X, is the same as a DC voltage of X * 0.707,

Mains say 240V AC is actually the RMS voltage, it has a peak voltage of 339V, but if you feed it into a resistance, it will only produce equivilent heating to a 240V DC source.

Comment: Which produces more heat 220sint volt AC or 220|sint| DC?

Comment: @user251774 what do you mean by "sint", that is not a term I am used to in this context,

Comment: sint- sine of angle t; t here used for time

Comment: Ok, a sinusoid with a peak value of 220V will produce 0.707x as much heat as a 220V DC Voltage, take the RMS value of the sinusoid if you wish to confirm.

Comment: 220sint AC and 220|sint| DC have same RMS value

Comment: a DC voltage does not have a sine component, do you perhaps mean 2 200V sine waves, 1 with a center of 0V, 1 with a center of 100V?

Comment: 220|Sint| Volt is dc voltage.

Comment: 220 |sin(t)| volts is full wave rectified AC with no smoothing. The heating will be the same because power is proportional to the square of the voltage so sign does not matter.

Comment: That changes things. Thank you for clarifying. The dc will be slightly less heat because the rectifier will reduce the voltage slighty. Meaning less voltage available for the load. So less current than straight ac would be drawn

Answer (score 0):

given the mostly random rebounding of electrons in a metal, with only a tiny fraction under the impetus of the electric field, the "changing of direction" comes at no extra energy cost.